# How to update the same value for new updated column in SQL Server for all rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have insert 10,000 rows into table which contains 3 columns.

Now i need to add the new column into table.And also need to store the value to updated column which is to be same for all 10,000 rows.

For example:

my table like below..,

```
No Name ID
1 raj 1000
2 ravi 1001
3 git  1002
..
.
.
10000 dat 10,000
```

Now i need to add the new column "date"
Then data like this..,

```
No Name ID   Date
1  raj  1001 
2  ravi  1002 
3   git  1003
```

I have using below query to add new column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD Date date
```

but i need to know how to store the same data into all rows in table like below.

```
No Name ID   Date
1  raj  1001  10.12.2020
2  ravi  1002 10.12.2020
3   git  1003 10.12.2020
.
.
.
.
10,000 dat 10000 10.12.2020
```

How can i achieve above requirement?

I am little bit know about sql server.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        ALTER TABLE table_name 
        ADD CONSTRAINT DF_date DEFAULT N'10.10.2020' FOR [date];

    or
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].table_name
            ADD CONSTRAINT DF_table_name_column_name DEFAULT ('10.10.2020') FOR column_name

 iam giving one example

CREATE TABLE #TEST(PART VARCHAR(10),LASTTIME DATETIME)
GO

ALTER TABLE [DBO].#TEST
        ADD CONSTRAINT DF_#TEST_LASTTIME DEFAULT ('10.10.2020') FOR LASTTIME
INSERT INTO #TEST (PART )
VALUES('A')

INSERT INTO #TEST (PART )
VALUES('B')

INSERT INTO #TEST (PART )
VALUES('AA')

INSERT INTO #TEST (PART )
VALUES('BA')


GO
```

Comment: If i use above command ,it shows "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'."

Comment: can i know what is "DF_date" constraint in your query?

Comment: default constraint df_column_name means on which column u need default value so in ur question date is defalut value we need to insert @Mahendran

Comment: i posted 2 answers for that question u can try any one @Mahendran

Comment: i have tried your query but no values inserted it shows NULL values only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126182/discussion-between-mahen-dran-and-venkatesh-rangu).

Comment: In your command works only if my table contains "TwoColumn" only.
If i have more than one two columns this command doesn't worked,Shows this error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition".

Comment: can u check second condition it will work for multiple columns

Comment: please follow this steps
1create table 
2.add multiple  columns
3.DefaultConstraint 
4.Insertion

Answer (score 0):

First only add new column to your table .

```
ALTER TABLE Protocols
ADD Date Date
```

After , For your past data ,you can use update query .

```
update Protocols set Date='10.12.2020' .
```

In last ,

```
ALTER TABLE Protocols 
ALTER COLUMN Date SET DEFAULT '10.12.2020'
```

It will be updating all your pass date with '10.12.2020' and in future also value for Date will be '10.12.2020' .

Thanks .